# Stop iCarousel labels from scrolling

Tags: ios, button, scroll, label, icarousel

All my labels, done button and back button are scrolling within my icarousel. Is there a way to stop them from moving with the swipe gesture or are they inherently fixed? Or is it a case of taking them out of the function all together?[image]

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

{
    GalleryImage* gi = [self.galleryItem.galleryImages objectAtIndex:index];

```
UIImageView* imageView = nil;
UILabel* positionLabel = nil;
//UILabel* titleLabel = nil;
UILabel* label = nil;
UIButton* doneButton = nil;
UIView* labelBackground = nil;
UIActivityIndicatorView * spinnerView = nil;
UILabel * errorMessage = nil;
UILabel* titleLabel = nil;

//create new view if no view is available for recycling
if (view == nil) {
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.carousel.frame.size.width, self.carousel.frame.size.height)] ;

    // Image
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.carousel.frame.size.width, self.carousel.frame.size.height)] ;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;// UIViewContentModeCenter;
    imageView.tag = 1;

    // Spiner
    spinnerView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [spinnerView setFrame:imageView.frame];
    spinnerView.tag = 11;

    //Error message
    errorMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:spinnerView.frame];
    [errorMessage setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [errorMessage setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    errorMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 14.0];
    errorMessage.tag = 111;

    [imageView addSubview:errorMessage];
    [imageView addSubview:spinnerView];
    [view addSubview:imageView];


    // Position
    positionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.carousel.frame.size.width, 30)] ;
    positionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    positionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    positionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    positionLabel.numberOfLines=1;
    positionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 14.0];
    positionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    positionLabel.tag = 2;

    //if(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait == self.interfaceOrientation)
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        // Title
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, self.carousel.frame.size.width - 20, 100)] ;
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size: 18.0];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n", self.galleryItem.title];
        [view addSubview:titleLabel];

        /*
         *  Manage carousel speed and deceleration rate for portrait mode
         */
        //self.carousel.decelerationRate = 0.175f;
        //self.carousel.scrollSpeed = 0.45f;
    }
    else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        /*
         *  Manage carousel speed and deceleration rate for landscape mode
         */
        //self.carousel.decelerationRate = 0.25f;
        //self.carousel.scrollSpeed = 0.55f;
    }

    labelBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.carousel.frame.size.height - 160, self.carousel.frame.size.width , 160)] ;
    CAGradientLayer *labelBackgroundGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    labelBackgroundGradient.frame = labelBackground.bounds;
    labelBackgroundGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor],
                                                                (id)[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor],
                                                                nil
                                      ];
    [labelBackground.layer insertSublayer:labelBackgroundGradient atIndex:0];

    labelBackground.opaque = false;
    labelBackground.tag = 5;

    // Description

    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(    0.0f,
                                                                    0.0f,
                                                                    labelBackground.bounds.size.width - 20.0f,
                                                                labelBackground.bounds.size.height)] ;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:12];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = gi.descriptionGalleryImage;
    [label autoAdjustGalleryCaptionSize];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(     label.bounds.origin.x + 10.0f,
                                    label.bounds.origin.y + (labelBackground.bounds.size.height - (label.bounds.size.height + 10.0f)),
                                    label.bounds.size.width,
                                    label.bounds.size.height
     )];
    label.tag = 6;

    [labelBackground addSubview:label];
    [view addSubview:labelBackground];

} else {
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    spinnerView = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)[imageView viewWithTag:11];
    errorMessage = (UILabel*) [imageView viewWithTag:111];
    positionLabel = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:2];
    doneButton = (UIButton *)[view viewWithTag:3];
    //titleLabel = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:4];
    labelBackground = (UIView *)[view viewWithTag:5];
    label = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:6];
}
//Start image loading
ImageSize* imSize = [gi getLargestImage];
[spinnerView startAnimating];
errorMessage.text = @"";

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imSize.source] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageContinueInBackground progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
    //progress bar could be here

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    //remove progressbar
    [spinnerView stopAnimating];

    //Display error message
    if(error)
    {
        //errorMessage.text = error.localizedDescription;
        errorMessage.text = @"Cannot load image";
    }

    //Assign image
    if(image)
    {
        [imageView setImage:image];
    }
}];

positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %ld", (index + 1), (long)[self.galleryItem.galleryImages count]];



UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.carousel.frame.size.width, 30)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
v.alpha = 0.6;

[view addSubview:v];
[view addSubview:positionLabel];


// Done button
doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 50, 30);
[doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_white"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
doneButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,5,0,5);
[doneButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:doneButton];

/*
 *  The description. Why are we setting the frame for the label multiple times?
 *  We need to do this so it can autoadjust its size and position according 
 *  to the text contained within it.
 */
[label setText:gi.descriptionGalleryImage];
[label autoAdjustGalleryCaptionSize];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(     label.bounds.origin.x + 10.0f,
                                label.bounds.origin.y + (labelBackground.bounds.size.height - (label.bounds.size.height + 10.0f)),
                                label.bounds.size.width,
                                label.bounds.size.height
                           )];



labelBackground.hidden = self.hideLandscapeDetails;
label.hidden = self.hideLandscapeDetails;
doneButton.hidden = self.hideLandscapeDetails;
positionLabel.hidden = self.hideLandscapeDetails;
v.hidden =self.hideLandscapeDetails;
titleLabel.hidden = self.hideLandscapeDetails;

self.tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showHideInfo:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:self.tap1];

// scroll portrait view to same index
if (self.delegate) {
    [self.delegate setReturnIndex:self.carousel.currentItemIndex];
}

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Image Gallery"     // Event category (required)
                                                      action:@"Gallery Image Viewed"  // Event action (required)
                                                       label:@"Picture swipe"          // Event label
                                                       value:[NSNumber numberWithLong:(index + 1)]] build]];    // Event value
return view;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The label should be above the iCarousel to do what you want, not inside the views of the carousel.

Comment: Do you think there might be an easier way of saying programatically no scrolling to those elements rather going through them and taking them out? bit hacky but might save me some time as this version will be scrapped soon!

Comment: Anything that you put inside viewForItemAtIndex will scroll, that's why the label must be independent from the carousel.